# EpollCreate1 doesn't seem to work for golang.org/x/sys/unix even inside of a docker alpine image

Tags: docker, sockets, go, epoll

I'm new to golang and I can't seem to get the EpollCreate1 or really any Epoll methods to work. I am on a Mac OS machine. So I've been trying to build the executable and run it in docker with a amd64 architecture and linux operating system.

I have tried using the amd 64 golang image. But no matter what I do. unix.EpollCreate1(0) will come up as undefined. I keep setting the GOOS env and GOARCH and I even confirmed by printing to the console that those ENV variables are set correctly. The executable is built fine with the command `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build`. However, the executable fails each time when actually run inside of the docker right at the line where the Epoll is referenced.

What am I missing? Can I only develop this code on a linux computer? I even tried setting the host env variables as well.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM amd64/golang:1.17.6
WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . ./

RUN env GOHOSTARCH=amd64 GOHOSTOS=linux GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o /start-app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/start-app" ]
```

And here is my docker compose yml

```
services:
  go-websockets: 
    build: .
    environment: 
    - REDIS_HOSTNAME=redis
    - REDIS_PASSWORD=redis
    - REDIS_PORT=6379
    - GOARCH=amd64
    - GOOS=linux
    - GOHOSTARCH=amd64
    - GOHOSTOS=linux
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - redis-volume:/data
    environment: 
    - REDIS_PASSWORD=redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    command: redis-server --requirepass redis
volumes:
  redis-volume:
    external: true
```

Here is my mod

```
module bitbucket.org/websockets

go 1.17

require (
    cloud.google.com/go/pubsub v1.17.1
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.7.7
    github.com/go-redis/redis v6.15.9+incompatible
    github.com/gobwas/ws v1.1.0
    go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.8.3
    google.golang.org/api v0.58.0
)

require (
    cloud.google.com/go v0.97.0 // indirect
    github.com/gin-contrib/sse v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/locales v0.13.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/universal-translator v0.17.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 v10.4.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-stack/stack v1.8.0 // indirect
    github.com/gobwas/httphead v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/gobwas/pool v0.2.1 // indirect
    github.com/golang/groupcache v0.0.0-20200121045136-8c9f03a8e57e // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2 // indirect
    github.com/golang/snappy v0.0.3 // indirect
    github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.6 // indirect
    github.com/googleapis/gax-go/v2 v2.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/json-iterator/go v1.1.9 // indirect
    github.com/klauspost/compress v1.13.6 // indirect
    github.com/leodido/go-urn v1.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.12 // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/concurrent v0.0.0-20180228061459-e0a39a4cb421 // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/reflect2 v0.0.0-20180701023420-4b7aa43c6742 // indirect
    github.com/onsi/ginkgo v1.16.5 // indirect
    github.com/onsi/gomega v1.18.1 // indirect
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/ugorji/go/codec v1.1.7 // indirect
    github.com/xdg-go/pbkdf2 v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/xdg-go/scram v1.0.2 // indirect
    github.com/xdg-go/stringprep v1.0.2 // indirect
    github.com/youmark/pkcs8 v0.0.0-20181117223130-1be2e3e5546d // indirect
    go.opencensus.io v0.23.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20201216223049-8b5274cf687f // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20210503060351-7fd8e65b6420 // indirect
    golang.org/x/oauth2 v0.0.0-20211005180243-6b3c2da341f1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20210220032951-036812b2e83c // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220209214540-3681064d5158 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.6 // indirect
    google.golang.org/appengine v1.6.7 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20211019152133-63b7e35f4404 // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.40.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.27.1 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0 // indirect
)
```

And here is the code in question

```
package handler

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "reflect"
    "sync"
    "syscall"

    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

type epoll struct {
    fd          int
    connections map[int]net.Conn
    lock        *sync.RWMutex
}

func MkEpoll() (*epoll, error) {
    fd, err := unix.EpollCreate1(0)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &epoll{
        fd:          fd,
        lock:        &sync.RWMutex{},
        connections: make(map[int]net.Conn),
    }, nil
}

func (e *epoll) Add(conn net.Conn) error {
    // Extract file descriptor associated with the connection
    fd := websocketFD(conn)
    err := unix.EpollCtl(e.fd, syscall.EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &unix.EpollEvent{Events: unix.POLLIN | unix.POLLHUP, Fd: int32(fd)})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    e.lock.Lock()
    defer e.lock.Unlock()
    e.connections[fd] = conn
    if len(e.connections)%100 == 0 {
        log.Printf("Total number of connections: %v", len(e.connections))
    }
    return nil
}

func (e *epoll) Remove(conn net.Conn) error {
    fd := websocketFD(conn)
    err := unix.EpollCtl(e.fd, syscall.EPOLL_CTL_DEL, fd, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    e.lock.Lock()
    defer e.lock.Unlock()
    delete(e.connections, fd)
    if len(e.connections)%100 == 0 {
        log.Printf("Total number of connections: %v", len(e.connections))
    }
    return nil
}

func (e *epoll) Wait() ([]net.Conn, error) {
    events := make([]unix.EpollEvent, 100)
    n, err := unix.EpollWait(e.fd, events, 100)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    e.lock.RLock()
    defer e.lock.RUnlock()
    var connections []net.Conn
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        conn := e.connections[int(events[i].Fd)]
        connections = append(connections, conn)
    }
    return connections, nil
}

func websocketFD(conn net.Conn) int {
    tcpConn := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(conn)).FieldByName("conn")
    fdVal := tcpConn.FieldByName("fd")
    pfdVal := reflect.Indirect(fdVal).FieldByName("pfd")

    return int(pfdVal.FieldByName("Sysfd").Int())
}
```

Comment: Note: `websocket` is a specific protocol that has its own specific JavaScript API (the tag refers to the protocol and the API), not a TCP/IP socket. You will want to use the `sockets` tag for socket related questions (I updated the tags in the question to fix this issue).